# Is there a better way to group date rangers in T-SQL than CASE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

At the moment I'm having to run a lot of SQL queries where the results have to be grouped by date ranges. So far I've been doing it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Don_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, - 24, getdate())
                AND GETDATE()
            THEN 1
        WHEN Don_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -48, GETDATE())
                AND DATEADD(month, - 24, getdate())
            THEN 2
        END AS DateRange
FROM #temp
GROUP BY CASE 
        WHEN Don_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, - 24, getdate())
                AND GETDATE()
            THEN 1
        WHEN Don_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -48, GETDATE())
                AND DATEADD(month, - 24, getdate())
            THEN 2
        END
```

Which works, but it's kind of a pain to write.

I'm having to do this quite a lot, and for a lot of different potential date ranges. Is there a better - as in easier to write/less verbose/more malleable - way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify it with a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT t.*
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Don_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, - 24, getdate())
                AND GETDATE()
            THEN 1
        WHEN Don_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -48, GETDATE())
                AND DATEADD(month, - 24, getdate())
            THEN 2
        END AS DateRange
    FROM #temp t
)
SELECT Count = COUNT(*), DateRange
FROM Ranges 
GROUP BY DateRange
```

Answer (score 2):

With a join to a virtual values table.

```
select 
    rangedesc,COUNT(*) 
from
    yourtable
        left join
    (values 
        (DATEADD(month,-24,getdate()),getdate(), 1),
        (DATEADD(month,-48,getdate()),DATEADD(month,-24,getdate()), 2)
    ) ranges(start,finish,rangedesc)
        on yourtable.don_date between ranges.start and ranges.finish
group by rangedesc
```

If you prefer, you could move the date ranges to a CTE.

Of course, as with all date comparisons, be careful with the borders between two ranges. Compared to your original source code, if a date falls exactly 2 years ago, this method would put it in both ranges, rather than just one.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
;WITH myDates (DateRange, dtStart, dtEnd)
AS (            SELECT 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -24, GETDATE()), DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())
    UNION ALL   SELECT 2, DATEADD(MONTH, -48, GETDATE()), DATEADD(MONTH, -24, GETDATE())
)
SELECT COUNT(*), DateRange 
FROM #temp
JOIN myDates ON don_date BETWEEN dtStart AND dtEnd
GROUP BY DateRange
```

Comment: Yes, why not post an answer that's equivalent to an existing answer.

Comment: @podiluska Also, your code doesn't run on my SQL Server 2005 DB.